# call a function of a flash script from another flash script

Tags: flash

Hello I'm a newbie of Flash, I'm trying to do the following:

in one flash page script I want to call a function belonging to another flash script, how to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: are the two swfs on the same page?

Comment: No they belong to two different pages

Comment: my idea is to load the other page and then call the function I want to call....I can load the other page...but then I don't know how to call the function...

Comment: I should have been more clear.  Are these being viewed in an internet browser?  If so, do both swfs appear on the same web-page?  Or, are you loading one page (say page1.html) and you want to call a function in a swf located on a separate page (page2.html)?

Comment: I explain, I have a page1.html (made in flash) if I push a button I wanna open page2.html (made in flash) and call a function belonging to this second one.
Hope I made it clear.

thanks in advance

Comment: AS2 or AS3?  Will the person be redirected a new page, or will this open page2 in addition to page1?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this using [`LocalConnection`](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/flash/net/LocalConnection.html).

Receiving SWF:

```
private var localConnection:LocalConnection
//inside constructor
{
  localConnection = new LocalConnection();
  //in case both SWF's are in different domains
  localConnection.allowDomain("sender.swf's.domain");
  //in case receiver is in HTTPS and sender is non-HTTPS
  localConnection.allowInsecureDomain("sender.swf's.domain");
  localConnection.connect("connectionName");
  localConnection.client = this;

  //initialize TextField (tf) here
}
public function writeMsg(msg:String):void
{
  tf.text += "\nReceived message\n" + msg;
}
```

Sending SWF:

```
private var localConnection:LocalConnection;
private var connectionName:String;
//inside the constructor
{
  connectionName = "connectionName"; //use the same name as in receiver 
  localConnection = new LocalConnection();
  localConnection.addEventListener(StatusEvent.STATUS, onStatus);
  localConnection.addEventListener(SecurityErrorEvent.SECURITY_ERROR, onSecError);
}

//to call the "writeMsg" function in the receiver SWF from sender SWF
localConnection.send(connectionName, "writeMsg", "It works!");

private function onStatus(e:StatusEvent):void
{
  trace("statusEventHandler: code = " + e.code + ", level = " + e.level);
}
private function onSecError(e:SecurityErrorEvent):void
{
  trace("unable to make LocalConnection due to Security Error: " + e.text);
}
```

Remember that local connections are simplex - the communications are one way. For two-way communication, you have to set up another pair of local connections and call `connect` from the appropriate SWF with a different connection name.

Comment: This is awesome. This was the "missing piece" I needed in order to implement a "connect with Facebook" workflow from within a Flash object...